# Visual C# Project's build fails with no errors?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

[image]

Here's the erroring line:

`ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();`

I know it needs arguments. Why am I not seeing any errors?

Comment: If you mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx then it has default constructor.

Comment: I have that page opened. My issue is that the Error List isn't outputting anything for me to go on whatsoever, for no reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to show errors on build failed: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" option. Check if it is selected.

Maybe will be helpful as well:

There is an [option to change the amount of information included in the build log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx):

> On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options. On the Projects and Solutions
>   page, choose the Build and Run page. In the MSBuild project build
>   output verbosity list, choose one of the following values, and then
>   choose the OK button.

Comment: Nevermind, I know how it became unchecked: I uninstalled ReSharper and forgot to reload Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for the information, because i had no clue how it became unchecked.